# std::call_once concurrent calls behavior

Tags: c++

I’m trying to execute a piece once and I’m using [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) to achieve this. Now, my question is the following, assuming that the executed piece of code takes a while to complete, what would be the behavior of the second caller, if the first caller hasn’t completed yet.

Will it return immediately or will it wait until the first complete before returning.

Ps: Both calls are from different threads and first call will succeed.

I did a small test to check the behavior. The second call returned after the first call was completed, but i couldn’t find any info whether this behavior is from the c++ standard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://eel.is/c++draft/thread#once.callonce :

> Synchronization: For any given once_flag: all active executions occur in a total order; completion of an active execution synchronizes with the start of the next one in this total order; and the returning execution synchronizes with the return from all passive executions.

Means only one `call_once` will enter at a time. So if you call it twice, the second one will wait for the first one to complete.

Answer (score 4):

Cppreference says [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) (emphasis mine):

> If, by the time std::call_once is called, flag indicates that f was already called, std::call_once returns right away[...].
> Otherwise, std::call_once calls INVOKE(std::forward(f), std::forward(args)...). [...]

> *If that invocation throws an exception, it is propagated to the caller of std::call_once, **and flag is not flipped** so that another call will be attempted* [...].

> *If that invocation returns normally* [...] flag is flipped, and all other calls to std::call_once with the same flag are guaranteed to be passive.

The call to `std::call_once` is thread safe and the flag is only set if the given function returns. So the behaviour you are experiencing is expected.

Comment: `If, by the time std::call_once` According to cppreference, the flag is flipped _after_ the function returns. So by the time the second call_once is called, the flag is not flipped, so two concurrent executions of the function should start. I do no understand how the 'if throws exception" part is relevant.

Comment: @KamilCuk yeah I removed too much of the quote. I have edited the answer. _I do no understand how the 'if throws exception" part is relevant._ -- This part is relevant to understand why it would wait to flip the flag.

Comment: It's even spelled out more explicitly later: "The return from the returning call synchronizes-with the returns from all passive calls on the same flag: this means that all concurrent calls to std::call_once are guaranteed to observe any side-effects made by the active call, with no additional synchronization."

Comment: `std::once_flag` has no public API functions other than a default constructor and `std::call_once`. It is neither copyable, nor movable. Implementation could simply be a `std::atomic<int>` with 3 valid states: initial, processing, done. So upon entry, `call_once` aquires *processing*; thrown exceptions are caught and rethrown after releasing to *initial*, and successful return aquires *done*.